# Using NASM and ld on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm, ld

I am a beginner in Assembly (in fact this is my first ever attempt), and I was wondering how I could get this x86 assembly code to run on my Mac using NASM and the ld linker.

```
SECTION .data           ; Section containing initialised data

    EatMsg: db "Eat at Joe's!",10
    EatLen: equ $-EatMsg    

SECTION .bss            ; Section containing uninitialized data 

SECTION .text           ; Section containing code

global  _start          ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

_start:
    nop         ; This no-op keeps gdb happy...
    mov eax,4       ; Specify sys_write call
    mov ebx,1       ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
    mov ecx,EatMsg      ; Pass offset of the message
    mov edx,EatLen      ; Pass the length of the message
    int 80H         ; Make kernel call

    MOV eax,1       ; Code for Exit Syscall
    mov ebx,0       ; Return a code of zero 
    int 80H         ; Make kernel call
```

This assembly code is from a book that is made for linux, however since both linux and mac are unix based operating systems, I assumed that the assembly code would be generally the same. I realize now that I may not be able to get this to a mac executable through nasm and ld, but if I can, how would I do so? And if not, how would I change this assembly code so that it does work, but does generally the same thing?

Comment: Thanks, but again, I am a complete beginner, would you mind explaining how I should call the standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sample code should work when assembled with nasm and linked using gcc (needs to link with the standard c library!)

```
SECTION .data           ; Section containing initialised data

    EatMsg: db "Eat at Joe's!",10
    EatLen: equ $-EatMsg

SECTION .bss            ; Section containing uninitialized data

SECTION .text           ; Section containing code

global main
extern write

main:
    sub esp, 12                 ; allocate space for locals/arguments
    mov dword [esp], 1          ; stdout
    mov dword [esp+4], EatMsg   ; Pass offset of the message
    mov dword [esp+8], EatLen   ; Pass the length of the message
    call write                  ; Make library call

    mov eax,0                   ; Return a code of zero
    add esp, 12                 ; restore stack
    ret
```

Note that "Hello world" is a particularly bad first asm program, and generally doing I/O and other high level things from asm is not recommended.

Comment: Great answer. The syntax and method for assembling and linking looks radically different than the linux, and I cant seem to find any good and thorough resources that focus on assembly for mac, does anyone know any?

Answer (score 3):

`int 80H` is deprecated on OS X, and in any case it uses different selectors than Linux. You should probably use `syscall` or call the standard C library instead.

<strike>See: [thexploit.com/secdev/mac-os-x-64-bit-assembly-system-calls](http://thexploit.com/secdev/mac-os-x-64-bit-assembly-system-calls) for a useful "Hello World" tutorial with nasm on Mac OS X.</strike>

See also: [daveeveritt.tumblr.com/post/67819832/webstraction-2-from-unix-history-and-assembly-language](http://daveeveritt.tumblr.com/post/67819832/webstraction-2-from-unix-history-and-assembly-language) for more info on using nasm to build an OS X executable.

Comment: thexploit link is 404'd. thexploit.com home page seems to be an empty apache server.

Comment: Thanks - I'll delete the dead link.